# I don't start win7 from grub2

Tags: 12.04, grub2

When I start Win7 from list. I see "file not found  grub rescue>". I don't know what is problem. I'm begginer with ubuntu 12.04.

log from boot repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/1357573

Comment: I see you have 3 entries with Windows. One is "recovery mode" OK, but other 2 appear the same. Did you try to boot on each entry ?

Comment: It looks like you have multiple hard drives. Is this true, and if so did you install Linux to the one with Windows on it or not? There are Windows-compatible partitions on both.

Comment: Oh, also, did you install from Windows (WUBI) or by booting the CD?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Home folder encryption ON, if yes then you have to reinstall the Ubuntu 12.04 with encryption OFF, and if no then I think you have installed grub in a wrong partition.